# Reveal File in File Explorer

Tags: command-line, windows, files, display, mac

I have a Java application in which I need to "reveal" a file to the user (i.e. open the containing folder of the file in an explorer and highlight the file).  I have configured it to do so in both Windows and Mac OSX, but I have not been able to find a terminal command to do so on Linux/Ubuntu operating systems.

The below batch/terminal commands are the Windows and Mac equivalents of what I am looking for.

Windows:

```
Explorer /select,filename
```

Mac:

```
open -R filename
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file manager in Ubuntu is called Nautilus, and it seems to do what you are after when you pass a file to it on the command line.  For instance, the following command:

```
nautilus ~/Documents/foo.txt
```

opens a file manager window showing the `~/Documents` folder with `foo.txt` selected.

Comment: Thanks! I have one question though: when I posted a related question on StackOverflow, I received a response which said "On Linux it would depend on the window manager or file browser they are using."  Would that command you posted work on most Ubuntu/Linux systems?

Comment: It should work for people using the Unity or GNOME desktops (Nautilus is the Gnome file manager).  You would need something different for Kubuntu or Xubuntu desktops.  There are cross-desktop tools like `xdg-open` that should open the desktop's file manager if you pass them a folder, but this doesn't give you a way to select a file in the folder.  If I used `xdg-open` in the example from my answer, it would instead open a text editor.

Comment: Although `xdg-open` doesn't reveal the file, I'll use that for Linux users so that functionality is ensured.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Dbus may be an option:

```
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.FileManager1 /org/freedesktop/FileManager1 org.freedesktop.FileManager1.ShowItems array:string:"file:///home/john.doe/foo.txt" string:""
```

Electron is using that and if it fails it falls back to

```
xdg-open /home/john.doe/
```

Which does not highlight the file